# Vue.js - Only display false array elements

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

If I have code like the code below in my vue.js, upon clicking a button, how can I only display the array item I clicked ( for e.g, Donnie) and hide all of the rest? (Joanne, Peter e.t.c), then when you click the only displayed element again, make all of the other array elements display again?

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    keyword: '',
    friends: [
      {
      name: "Donnie",
      age: "20"
    },
    {
        name: "Joanne",
        age:"19",
     },
      {
      name: "David",
      age: "26"
    },
      {
      name: "Peter",
      age: "23"
    },
      {
      name: "John",
      age: "29"
    },
      {
      name: "Jason",
      age: "19"
    },
     ],
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.friends.filter((friend) => {
        return friend.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword) + friend.age.includes(this.keyword) + friend.name.includes(this.keyword);
      });

      }
    },

  methods:{
      exclude(friend) {
        console.log(!friend.name);
    },
  }

  })
```

HTML

```
   <div v-for="friend in filteredList" class="card" @click="exclude(friend)">
      {{friend.name}} - {{friend.age}}
    </div>
```

Comment: this is simple question and does not even have to do anything with vuejs, it is a js question

Comment: Sorry, still learning, could you help me with the code?

Comment: Your filter expression is using an odd choice of operator. You probably want `||`, not `+` though I guess adding the numeric equivalents of `true` or `false` have a similar effect

Comment: @Phil Sounds like he wants `&&`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I still think `||`. When treated as numbers, Boolean addition works the same as **OR** in that any `true` (or `1`) makes the expression _truthy_

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add an identity check to your filter expression if an item has been clicked.

Start by adding a property to store the clicked *friend*. I'll call mine *selected*

```
data {
  selected: null,
  keyword: '',
  //etc
}
```

Then in your `exclude` method

```
exclude (friend) {
  this.selected = this.selected ? null : friend
}
```

now your computed property can filter the list based on the `selected` friend first, then fall back to the keyword match

```
filteredList () {
  return this.selected ? [this.selected] : this.friends.filter(friend => {
    let search = this.keyword.trim().toLowerCase()
    return friend.name.toLowerCase().includes(search) || friend.age.includes(search)
  })
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but you should probably also lower-case the keyword.

Comment: @puelo was just using the same expression as in OP's code but good point. Updated

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you're looking for:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    keyword: '',
    friends: [
      {
        name: "Donnie",
        age: "20"
      },
      {
        name: "Joanne",
        age:"19",
      },
      {
        name: "David",
        age: "26"
      },
      {
        name: "Peter",
        age: "23"
      },
      {
        name: "John",
        age: "29"
      },
      {
        name: "Jason",
        age: "19"
      },
    ],
    selected: null
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      if (!this.selected) {
        return this.friends.filter((friend) => {
          return friend.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword) + friend.age.includes(this.keyword) + friend.name.includes(this.keyword);
        });
      } else {
        return [this.selected];
      }
    },
  },

  methods:{
    exclude(friend) {
      if(!this.selected) {
        this.selected = friend;
      } else {
        this.selected = null;
      }
    },
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="friend in filteredList" class="card" @click="exclude(friend)">
      {{friend.name}} - {{friend.age}}
    </div>
</div>
```

The trick here is that the `selected` data property store the friend and also doubles as a checker if there's a friend, so if not, show all, if is, show only that one.

Comment: You're missing the keyword search

Comment: You're right, thank you for the heads up, edited the answer.